# Is there a VLOOKUP function using IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, formula, vlookup

I'm trying to generate a payroll test using Idea. The test consists of extracting duplicate bank account numbers and home addresses from an employee Masterfile. I have used the duplicate key function and it worked, but now I have a file with duplicates and would like to exclude those from the employee Masterfile. I was thinking of generating a formula that searches for employee IDs on the duplicate file and compares it to the employee Masterfile, and if found have them removed or exclude them from the employee Masterfile.

[image]

Comment: Try looking at the `Collections` framework in java. You can represent your data with `List` or `Set`. Then, adding or subtracting items from list is easy.

Comment: Ty using diff/compare between two files/tables (you can edit CSV file as a table in IDE). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/differences-viewer.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-format-configuration-dialog.html , https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/differences-viewer-for-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no Vlookup type formula in IDEA. What you want to do is use the Join tool in IDEA to create a match, or no-match in your case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).